# Can we make a generic function which can take both mobile element and web element?

Tags: selenium, appium

```
public static < E > void clickOnElement( E element ) {

    }
```

I am trying to make one generic function which can take element type as WebElement when using selenium and MobileElement when using appium ,so that i can peform click event. Anyone having idea how to implement?

Answer (score 1):

Since `MobileElement`implements the `WebElement` interface, you can simply use `WebElement` object itself for your `click()` method.

Considering, you still want to make a generic method anyways, you can achieve it without using `Generics`, simply use `Object`class:

```
public static void clickOnElement(Object element ) {

String className = element.getClass().getName();

if(className.contains('WebElement'))
{
 //do your WebElement stuff
}

else if(className.contains('MobileElement'))
{
 //do your MobileElement stuff
}
}
```